# CoreFoundation error when archiving and not when building

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to archive my application to submit/upload it for update purposes.
When I'm selecting iOS simulator I have no errors and the project is running, however, when selecting iOS device and then Archive, I have an error in 
`#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>`
`'CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h' file not found`
I tried to remove and then re-insert CoreFoundation and nothing helps.
Did you face that problem before? 
I also noticed that the framework are in red, and I can't find CoreFoundation when searching for it.
Thank you for helping

Comment: Double-check your capitalisation - Simulator isn't case-sensitive in certain circumstances but devices are.

Comment: @davidf2281 I really don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add to the .pch file this:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#endif
```

This will make the Foundation visible for the entire project.

Good Luck

Comment: I already found `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` and added to it CoreFoundation, however, no hope.